# DNS problem with plesk panel while using name servers

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I purchased a domain www.softmail.me at Godaddy.com and tried it DNS and getting lots of errors and finally change my nameservers to my server DNS i.e. NS101.VPSLAND.COM and NS202.VPSLAND.COM and created a domain in my plesk panel (Marked DNS & Mail required). After adding my domain to my plesk panel of my server I opened DNS records of that domain and found DNS records are automatically generated to my needs as following

---

```
65.75.241.26 / 24   PTR softmail.me.
ftp.softmail.me.    CNAME   softmail.me.
lists.softmail.me.  CNAME   softmail.me.
mail.softmail.me.   A   65.75.241.26
mssql.softmail.me.  A   65.75.241.26
ns.softmail.me. A   65.75.241.26
sitebuilder.softmail.me.    A   65.75.241.26
softmail.me.    NS  ns.softmail.me.
softmail.me.    A   65.75.241.26
softmail.me.    MX (10) mail.softmail.me.
webmail.softmail.me.    A   65.75.241.26
www.softmail.me.    CNAME   softmail.me.
```

---

Finally I waited for a week for I am unable to use my domain. Also in DNS lookup I cannot find any records to my Server except name servers of VPSland. Do I need to add VPSland namesevers anywhere in Plesk panel? If so where? Can anyone assist me where the mistake is?...