# dns configuration error in plesk

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

I purchased a domain www.softmail.me at Godaddy.com and tried it DNS and getting lots of errors and finally change my nameservers to my server DNS i.e. NS101.VPSLAND.COM and NS202.VPSLAND.COM and created a domain in my plesk panel (Marked DNS & Mail required). After adding my domain to my plesk panel of my server I opened DNS records of that domain and found DNS records are automatically generated to my needs as following

```
65.75.241.26 / 24   PTR softmail.me.
ftp.softmail.me.    CNAME   softmail.me.
lists.softmail.me.  CNAME   softmail.me.
mail.softmail.me.   A   65.75.241.26
mssql.softmail.me.  A   65.75.241.26
ns.softmail.me. A   65.75.241.26
sitebuilder.softmail.me.    A   65.75.241.26
softmail.me.    NS  ns.softmail.me.
softmail.me.    A   65.75.241.26
softmail.me.    MX (10) mail.softmail.me.
webmail.softmail.me.    A   65.75.241.26
www.softmail.me.    CNAME   softmail.me.
```

Finally I waited for a week for I am unable to use my domain. Also in DNS lookup I cannot find any records to my Server except name servers of VPSland. Do I need to add VPSland namesevers anywhere in Plesk panel? If so where? Can anyone assist me where the mistake is?...

Comment: Exact dup of: http://serverfault.com/questions/284315/dns-problem-with-plesk-panel-while-using-name-servers

Comment: You don't need to repost questions that get migrated.

Comment: Of course but I didn't get answer for it... Also it went down. No one bothering about old questions.

Comment: There are 2 answers to it that precede your posting this question. Both of which say the same as the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nameserver `ns101.vpsland.com` and `ns202.vpsland.com` seem to not know your zone.
Check here: http://www.simpledns.com/lookup-dg.aspx

I guess you are not the owner of these servers.
You need to tell your provider of those two nameservers that you want to use their servers as authoritative nameservers for your domain.

Answer (score 0):

NS101.VPSLAND.COM and NS202.VPSLAND.COM don't report that they are name servers for softmail.me. You need to configure both to be authoratative for your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the domain isn't found on the vpsland.com nameservers

```
$ nslookup softmail.me NS101.VPSLAND.COM
Server:     NS101.VPSLAND.COM
Address:    64.22.102.251#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find softmail.me: No answer
```

You need to talk to vpsland

Comment: Can you please explain me bit clearly...

Comment: vpsland is not responding to this issue

Comment: But I took dns look up at zonedit and found my NS records points to NS101.VPSLAND.com and NS202.VPSland.com